# Get number of files to download with svn update

Tags: svn

I want to find a number of files which will be downloaded after `svn update` is run in command line. Need this to make a progress bar in a GUI application which uses svn to download updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `svn status --show-updates` to get the list of files which have been updated in the repository since your last update **as well as** files which have changed locally. You need to look at/parse the 9th column. From `svn help status`:

> The out-of-date information appears in the ninth column (with -u):
>         '*' a newer revision exists on the server
>         ' ' the working copy is up to date

But please don't use the command-line client for this - use the equivalent method in the svn library/package for the language you're building this application in.

Be advised that this won't give users an **accurate** progress bar though - if you have two files, one of which is 50KB of data to download and the other 50MB, after the first file is complete you're going to tell them that they're "50% complete" when in fact they have a **long** wait ahead of them.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no other/simpler way to just get the number of files needed to be downloaded, is it? I'm using command line svn, it's sufficient for application needs for now.

Comment: That is **the** way to do it. Command-line svn may be "sufficient" but you're adding extra dependencies and complexity to your application - a library is the more appropriate way to use it. If you consider parsing text to be "sufficient" as opposed to using proper objects output by a library...